# GDB Error in re-setting breakpoint (cannot access memory) after fork

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, fork, breakpoints

GDB does not set the same breakpoints in created forks. However, it should do it according to the [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html) (if I understand it correctly):

> If you have a breakpoint set on main in your original program, the breakpoint will also be set on the child process’s main.

I am also getting the following error for each set breakpoint:

```
Error in re-setting breakpoint 7: Cannot access memory at address 0x606682
Error in re-setting breakpoint 8: Cannot access memory at address 0x606682
Error in re-setting breakpoint 10: Cannot access memory at address 0x606682
```

It's probably worth to mention that I can set breakpoints after the fork was created as follows:

```
catch fork
cont
step
break file.cc:42
cont
```

GDB version is `GNU gdb (Debian 7.12-6) 7.12.0.20161007-git`